# Are there other methods to achieve a similar effect to filter: grayscale in IE10+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grayscale

I am using

```
filter: grayscale(42%);
```

to set the grayscale of some background images. This is obviously not supported in IE10/11 and nor are their old propriety filters. I can't use SVGs unfortunately (the images are uploaded via the CMS without the ability to manually change the image files as the users will not be capable).

As a result I wanted to see if there is anyway to achieve a similar effect to the grayscale filter using JS/JQuery or using a semi transparent overlay of some kind so I can get it working in newer versions of IE?

I've found a number of pollyfills (eg https://github.com/karlhorky/gray / https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite / http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js-v2-0-with-browser-feature-detection-using-modernizr/) however all appear to make the image fully gray scale and don't allow partial grayscale to be used (eg 42%).

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: If you're looking for a 'partial' grayness, have you thought of using a gray pseudo element with an opacity?

Comment: @jbutler483: Yes i have tried that but it creates a different effect to the grayscale filter unfortunately :(

Comment: It would be (probably) one of the few ways to achieve this in IE, albeit using an image.

Comment: But it creates a different effect so sadly doesn't really seem like an alternative/equivalent :(

Comment: [This page](http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html) on the site that you mention, links to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/487/) that seems to do what you want (the bottom two images have "partial grayscale").

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, i did see that but i'm trying to avoid using inline SVGs although from what i can now see that is the only way. As a result i've reverted to grayscaling/desaturation using PHP/GD on upload rather than using CSS/SVGs but thanks for your help